# Javascript opener window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have function that opens up a window, and the values from the newly opened window are listed in the opener window.
 The 2nd window - has this function:

```
function AddOtherRefDoc(name, number) {
    var remove = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='removeRefDoctor(this)'>Remove</a>";
    var html = "<li><b> Referral Doctor: </b>"+name+"<b>, Referral No: </b>"+number+ " " +remove+" <input type='text' name='ref_docs' value='"+name+"'></input><input type='text'  name='ref_nos' value='"+number+"'></input></li>";
    opener.jQuery("#r_docs").append(jQuery(html));
}
```

The function that calls the one above is:

```
function addRefDoc(){

    var count = 0;
    var ref_docarray ;
    var ref_noarray ;

    <%for(int i1=0; i1<vec.size(); i1++) {
        prop = (Properties) vec.get(i1);
        String ref_no = prop.getProperty("referral_no","");
        String ref_name = (prop.getProperty("last_name", "")+ ","+ prop.getProperty("first_name", ""));
    %>
    if(document.getElementById("refcheckbox_<%=ref_no%>").checked) {
        count++;

        if ((ref_doctor!=null)&&(ref_doctor!="")&&(ref_docno!=null)&&(ref_docno!="")) {
            ref_docarray = ref_doctor.split(";");
            ref_noarray = ref_docno.split(";");

            if ((containsElem(ref_docarray,"<%=ref_name%>"))||(containsElem(ref_noarray,<%=ref_no%>))) {
                alert("Referral doctor " + "<%=ref_name%>" + " already exists");
            } else {
                AddOtherRefDoc("<%=ref_name%>", <%=ref_no%>);
            }
        } else {
            AddOtherRefDoc("<%=ref_name%>", <%=ref_no%>);
        }
    } 

    <%} %>

    self.close();
}

function containsElem(array1,elem) {
    for (var i=0;i<array1.length;i++) {
        if(array1[i]==elem){
        return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

When this function is called, it is supposed to carry the 2 input elements "ref_docs" and "ref_nos" into the page that opened this window. But it is not doing so. It lists the elements alright but when I try to use "ref_docs" and "ref_nos" in another Javascript function in the 1st window, I see that "ref_nos" and  "ref_docs" are empty.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function updateRd(){ 
   var ref_docs = jQuery("#updatedelete").find('input[name="ref_docs"]'); 
   var ref_nos = jQuery("#updatedelete").find('input[name="ref_nos"]');                       alert(ref_docs.val() + ref_nos.val()); 
  var rdocs = new Array(); 
  var rnos = new Array(); 
  ref_docs.each(function() { rdocs.push($(this).val()); } ); 
  ref_nos.each(function() { rnos.push($(this).val()); } );                               
  $('#r_doctor').val(rdocs.join(";")); 
$('#r_doctor_ohip').val(rnos.join(";")); }
```

–
This function returns an error saying "ref_docs" and "ref_nos" are undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is trying to use the jQuery on the other page to find "#r_docs" on the current page.

Try:

```
jQuery(opener.document).find("#r_docs").append(html);
```

**UPDATE:**

I created index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.jQuery = jQuery;
  function openChild ()
  {
      var mychildwin = window.open("child.html");
  }
  </script>
  </head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="click" onclick="openChild();" />

<div id="r_docs">
Redocs here.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and child.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function AddOtherRefDoc(name, number) {
        var remove = "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='removeRefDoctor(this)'>Remove</a>";
        var html = "<li><b> Referral Doctor: </b>"+name+"<b>, Referral No: </b>"+number+ " " +remove+" <input type='text' name='ref_docs' value='"+name+"'></input><input type='text'  name='ref_nos' value='"+number+"'></input></li>";
        jQuery(opener.document).find("#r_docs").append(html);
    }
  </script>
  </head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="click" onclick="AddOtherRefDoc('name', 42);"/>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE2:**

in your update function `document.updatedelete` has no attributes ref_docs and ref_nos.

try:

```
jQuery("#updatedelete")
    .find('input[name="ref_docs"], input[name="ref_nos"]')
```

Where your form is

```
<form id="updatedelete" ... >
```

Comment: No, this didn't work. the bullets are not even showing up with this code like they did previously.

Comment: opener.document is showing the bullets but it's not saving the input values of ref_docs and ref_nos.

Comment: @James Khoury console says "ref_docs" and "ref_nos" are undefined when I try to use them in another Javascript function.

Comment: How are you using the function? In my example I passed in static values. are you able to show a bit more html?

Comment: I am passing values based on the checkboxes selected from the newly opened page.

Comment: You should be doing something like `AddOtherRefDoc(jQuery('#ref_docs').val(), jQuery('#ref_docs').val());` It would help to see some more code.

Comment: unfortunately Java is not my language of choice. can you show me the javascript output of the second code? What does the browser see?

Comment: should your tags not be `<%="\"" + ref_name + "\""%>` instead of `"<%=ref_name%>"`

Comment: Here's a screenshot of what happens when Add Ref Doctor button is clicked and docs are selected: http://uploadpic.org/v.php?img=vyY0Zvt2l6

Comment: That is the html rendered not the javascript/html. Though it looks like what i got ... what were you expecting different?

Comment: I am trying to use those input values and create a String to persist into the db. Please check the function I added.

Comment: @sapphire What is `document.updatedelete`? it seems that it has no attributes `ref_docs` and `ref_nos.` If you are trying to get the fields try `jQuery('input[name="ref_docs"]')`

Comment: document.updatedelete is the form on the opener window. I used that because I thought "ref_docs" now become a part of the opener window because they are being displayed there.

Comment: I don't think that works with dynamically added html. Try using jQuery instead. `jQuery('#updateDelete').find('input[name="ref_docs"]') etc etc` where your form has the **id** of `"updatedelete"`

Comment: Will this work if I have multiple input tags with the same name?

Comment: this will find all of them inside the element with the ID of `updatedelete`

Comment: @Sapphire have you made the **id** of the form `'updatedelete'` not just it's **name**?
`<form id="updatedelete" name="updatedelete" ...`

Comment: @Sapphire There was a small typo in my **UPDATE2** code if that was the part not working. Are you able to be more specific? What is not working. What is working?

Comment: Yes the id  of the form is "updatedelete", the problem is that ref_docs and ref_nos are empty. SO the code is not retrieving the values right at this stage: jQuery("#updatedelete")
    .find('input[name="ref_docs"], input[name="ref_nos"]')
.

Comment: Here's what I'm doing: var ref_docs = jQuery("#updatedelete").find('input[name="ref_docs"]');
var ref_nos = jQuery("#updatedelete").find('input[name="ref_nos"]');

Comment: @Sapphire and `ref_nos.val()` is ... nothing? Add `alert( name + " " + number);` in your `function AddOtherRefDoc` what happens?

Comment: @Sapphire check out http://jsfiddle.net/yb9zG/ on its own the AddOtherRefDoc function works fine.

Comment: alert(name + "" + number); is showing the values but when I do alert(ref_docs.val() + ref_nos.val()); in updateRd() function, it displays "NaN".

Comment: I checked http://jsfiddle.net/yb9zG/, my code displays those bullets too, but I want to use those values nd persist them into the db. when I try that in updateRd() in my parent html, it returns NaN.

Comment: @Sapphire try `alert(ref_docs.val() + " -- " + ref_nos.val());` instead of `alert(ref_docs.val() + ref_nos.val());`

Comment: Now it says "undefined -- undefined". Something wrong in accessing these values. updateRd() is in the parent window and AddOtherRefDoc() is in the child window. AddOtherRefDoc() is displaying those bullets in the parent window so why can't I access them ?

Comment: @Sapphire After AddOtherRefDoc() adds the lines in can you see values in the inputs?

Comment: Yes I can see the values in the input fields.

Comment: @Sapphire I'm assuming that the `function updateRd()` is being call **from** the parent window? and it is being called **after** the inputs are being added? After that I would check for typos and then try it in chrome and inspect the html.

Comment: @Sapphire I'd also write a smaller version and see if the concept works on a small test page(s).

Comment: I put the function updateRd() in the child window and it works now!

Answer (score 1):

Your function that accesses the DOM elements is incorrect.  `updatedelete` is not a property of `document`, nor will accessing a `ref_docs` or `ref_nos` property automatically build a collection of `input` elements.  Since you're using jQuery already, try this:

```
var ref_docs = $('input[name="ref_docs"]');
var ref_nos = $('input[name="ref_nos"]');
```

That will give you Array (or at least array-like) objects that will let you access your inputs:

```
var rdocs = new Array();
var rnos = new Array();

ref_docs.each(function() { rdocs.push($(this).val()); } );
ref_nos.each(function() { rnos.push($(this).val()); } );

$('#r_doctor').val(rdocs.join(";"));
$('#r_doctor_ohip').val(rnos.join(";"));
```

Comment: You're using the wrong document. Keep in mind that by default, jQuery uses the "current document" (which is the one which contains the `script` tag you used to load jQuery). If you want to locate tags in a different document (like a frame or a different window), you have to tell jQuery so.